# Plugin / Configuration for VLC able to show speed buttons

Tags: vlc

Often I need to increase or decrease speed of the video I watch with VLC.

Is out of there a plugin that could add speed controls near main VLC buttons?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the speed controls near main VLC buttons through the toolbars editor (drag-and-drop "speed selector" to the toolbar):

[image]